# Laravel 9 dompdf error "Image not found or type unknown"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dompdf

"Something strange is happening on my Apache 2 server in production where I've deployed my Laravel app. When the server is restarted, all the images in my PDF display correctly, but at some point, the images stop showing up, and I get the message 'image not found or type unknown.' I have to restart my Apache server for everything to return to normal.

I've verified that GD is installed and enabled. I can access my images without any problem in their directories. How can I resolve this issue?"
"php": "^8.1",
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",

```
$path_country_logo      = public_path('logos/' . env('COUNTRY_LOGO'));
$extension_logo_country = pathinfo($path_country_logo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data_country_logo      = file_get_contents($path_country_logo);
$country_logo           = "data:image/$extension_logo_country;base64," .                base64_encode($data_country_logo);

$path_app_logo          = public_path('logos/' . env('APP_LOGO'));
$extension_logo_app     = pathinfo($path_app_logo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data_app_logo          = file_get_contents($path_app_logo);
$app_logo               = "data:image/$extension_logo_app;base64," . base64_encode($data_app_logo);

$pdf = PDF::setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled', true])->loadView('layouts.report', [
    'country_logo'      => $country_logo,
    'app_logo'          => $app_logo,

]);
return $pdf->output();
```

My blade

```
<div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
        <img src="{{ $country_logo }}" class="logo_class">

        <img src="{{ $app_logo }}" class="app_logo">
    </div>`
</div>
```

I want to display images in my PDF. I have followed many tutorials, but nothing has worked.

"php": "^8.1",
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",

Comment: I'd start by checking what your `$country_logo` actually contained when the error occurs, resp. what exactly made its way into the template.

Comment: This is the result when I use @dd($country_logo). I can access the image successfully, but I need to restart the server for the images to display. Could this be a server issue? Locally, everything works perfectly.

"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAE4gAAA0FCAYAAADIV2deAAAACXBIWXMAAFIFAABSBQEcrXESAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB3d3cuaW5rc2NhcGUub3Jnm+48GgAAIABJREFUeJzs3E ▶"

Comment: That is quite a large image, in pixel size (5000 * 3333 px) - is that actually what you are using? (What for?) I guess you could probably be running into memory issues, if something doesn't correctly get garbage collected, or something like that.